# Infinitely many primes don't split?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Milne's note says when $L,K$ are number fields and $L/K$ is an abelian extension, infinitely many primes don't split. I want to ask if it's right in general case and how to prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: Overkill: Chebotarev's density theorem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem

Comment: I believe existence of non-split primes in abelian extensions was historically the main stumbling block for providing fully algebraic proofs of class field theory (but don't quote me on that historical account). An algebraic proof now exists, I believe due to Chevalley, but is quite involved, see Proposition VII.4.6 of Milne's CFT. There is a simpler analytic proof too (which works in all Galois extensions), see Theoren VI.4.6 ibidem.

Comment: You can use Chebotarev's density theorem as François said, or mimick the proof of Dirichlet's theorem in this particular case. All you need to know is that $L$ is the class field of some congruence class group $I_{\mathfrak m}/H$ of $K$, and that a prime of $K$ splits in $L$ if and only if it is in $H$.

Answer (score 10):

Assume that all but finitely many primes split in $L/K$. Then the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_L(s)$ agrees with $\zeta_K(s)^{(L:K)}$ apart from finitely many Euler factors. Comparing the order of the pole $s=1$, we conclude that $(L:K)=1$, that is, $L=K$.

**Added.** I understood split as "completely split". If split is understood as "has at least one degree one prime over it", then the above still works with some modifications. I am grateful to Levent Alpoge for this observation (see his comment below).

Comment: Why do you get a power of $\zeta_K$? Doesn't that need the stronger assumption that all but finitely many primes split *completely* in $L$? (I read "don't split" as "inert", but maybe I misread the question.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: I understood split as "completely split".

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn If you interpret "don't split" as "stay inert", then this is false if $L/K$ is not cyclic. Indeed, if $\mathfrak p$ stays inert (in particular is unramified), then $Gal(L/K)$ injects into the Galois group of the residue fields, which is cyclic.

Comment: Why is it considerably harder? In the Galois closure L’/K the expected density (= 1/[L’:K]) of primes of K split completely in L’ (same Dedekind zeta argument). Hence the density of primes of K that split completely in L is at least 1/[L’:K]. The rest (forgetting a finite set) have at least one degree one prime over them. That’s too big by the Dedekind zeta argument (1 + ([L:K]-1)/[L’:K]\leq 1 implies L = K).

Comment: @alpoge: Thanks, that's a nice observation! I updated my post accordingly.